# java.util.function.Function as an interface for an mutable object

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability

I have an interface with only a single method that could be replaced by java.util.function.Function from the JDK:

```
interface DataModel {
  boolean apply(Map<String, Integer> input);
}
```

The replacement would be

```
Function<Map<String, Integer>, Boolean>
```

However, I wonder whether I should keep this interface since at least one implementation (other implementations might follow) contains mutable state and is not thread safe. A factory creates a new instance for each call.

So while technically possible, the functional interface might semantically not the best solution.

The API documentation doesn't say something about mutability, but maybe it would violate the principle of least astonishment or some other kind of contract. Is there any such contract?

Would you go with `Function` or with the custom `DataModel` interface and why?

Comment: What problem are you solving?  That's what dictates whether I use `Function` or not.  If you are doing functional programming where you have to provide a function, I would lean toward the `Function` interface since that speaks toward the functional mindset better.  If I'm in a more DDD environment I would probably favor `DataModel`.  Context is everything.

Comment: It is not a functional programming context. The interface is only accidental functional (what could be the answer to my question ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would got for `DataModel` interface, to avoid future missunderstandings and problems.
I not a Imperative/OO or Functional purist, but I think keeping things clear is a good thing.
`@FunctionalInterface`s has it's own purposes, I think custom interfaces always will fit better for "concrete implementations"; you own them, so you can extend and document them whenever you want or need.
Finally, try to avoid this scenario: *"a new change will force us to migrate `Funtion`s implementations to `BiFunction`s, or anything else"*; imagine the refactorings...
Something you can do is extend `Function`, to have your own copy of the interface and reuse default methods if needed:

```
public interface DataModel<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {}
```

Comment: Tanks, I go with my plain `DataModel` interface since it is only accidentally a functional interface.